# Is there a way to remove a Trait from an instance in Scala?

Tags: scala, traits

I would like to know if having an instance to which a trait has been added to in runtime, it is possible to remove the trait off the instance, so it can behave as originally.

Comment: You can't add traits at runtime.  So I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: Could you give an example of what you mean by adding a trait at runtime to an instance? I ask because, as far as I know, traits can only be mixed in at compile time. For details about how it works at the JVM level, see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7057166/how-does-the-scala-compiler-handle-concrete-trait-methods/7057723#7057723

Comment: He's presumably thinking of `new Foo with Bar`. This pattern looks like a dynamic mixin, but it's all static.  It just creates an anonymous class that mixes Bar into Foo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible. That instance belongs to a class of which the trait's code is part of.

If JVM supported something like "class+traits", then it would be theoretically possible to revert that.

Answer (score 5):

Traits are combined with classes at compile-time. So it is not possible to add/remove traits at run-time.

For your particular case, consider adding a method to your class:

```
class Foo(val a: Object, val b: Object, ...) {
  def original() = new Foo(a, b, ...)
}
```

Then you can call `instance.original()` to get back a copy of your object that is not affected by any traits.